# How to cut a string and send it to 'cd' command

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to write a little shell script that will help update packages from AUR on my ArchLinux. More to practise writing shell scripts than anything else. I send it the git repository link as argument, and later it needs to get the folder name that depends on the git link.

```
echo "$1" | sed 's/.*\///' | sed 's/\.git//'
```

If my git link is `https://aur.archlinux.org/example.git`, it will write `example` to terminal. This is expected.
But if I do

```
cd "$1" | sed 's/.*\///' | sed 's/\.git//'
```

It tries to change to the directory that is named the same as the link.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Note:  for readability, the `/` can be *anything*, so this `sed 's#.*/##'` is better than this `sed 's/.*\///'`.  Even letters work -- try:  `sed 'selective;settee' <<< 'better ale'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cd` command is failing because as you've written it, the input being processed by `sed` is the output of the `cd` command itself, rather than the text of the `$1` variable.

But you don't need `sed` to strip out parts of a string, you can do that with parameter expansion alone:

```
$ link='https://aur.archlinux.org/example.git'
$ echo "$(link="${link##*/}"; printf '%s' "${link%.git}")"
example
```

However, if you're trying to `cd` to the `example` directory, the following might work in your script, using the `BASH_REMATCH` array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

link="$1"

if [[ $link =~ ^https?://.*/([^.]+).git$ ]]; then
  cd "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
  printf 'Invalid link: %s\n' "$link"
fi
```